# npm-live-server https command line configuration?

Tags: npm, npm-live-server

I am running live server from command line:

```
live-server --port=8282 --host=192.168.1.231 --https=/home/.nvm/versions/node/v14.8.0/lib/node_modules/live-server-https --entry-file=/index.html
```

I would like to add my own cert like example below:

```
{
  "liveServer.settings.https": {
    "enable": true, //set it true to enable the feature.
    "cert": "D:\\https\\primary.crt", //full path of the certificate
    "key": "D:\\https\\private.key", //full path of the private key
    "passphrase": "12345"
  }
}
```

What is a correct format in .live-server.json or cmd line argument?

Comment: does this help https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/live-server-https

Comment: i did this already and HTTPS is working. Now I need to add my certificate - getting error testing on  web browsers using live-server certificate, wanted to add my certificate. Error:

Comment: ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://192.168.1.231:8282/') with script ('https://192.168.1.231:8282/service-worker.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.

Comment: i fixed this using Chrome flags --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://l192.168.1.231 and chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost. I cannot do that in mobile (Android/IOs) browsers, so wanted to use my own certificate.